# How to use external webcamera in video call?

Tags: video-calling, webcam, video-conference

I connected an external webcam to my Android phone, and it works well with apps like "USB Camera." However, I'm having trouble finding a video call app that supports external webcams.

I noticed that bjoster had a similar issue in a thread about 5 years ago, but since it's been a while, I decided to create a new thread. You can check out the previous discussion here: [How to use external OTG webcam for video calls/conference/talks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207672/how-to-use-external-otg-webcam-for-video-calls-conference-talks)

Has anyone managed to get it to work? If so, which app did you use?

I've already tried the following apps without success:

```
Teams
Skype
WhatsApp
Messenger
Google Meet
Zoom
```

I also attempted Webex, but it seems that only the old "Webex Meet" (or Meeting) app supports an external webcam. Unfortunately, I can't create a new meeting in the old app since I'm on the "new" Webex plan. Additionally, I can only get it to work using my webcam at work, not the one at home that I would prefer to use. The new Webex app lacks the external webcam feature.

Another potential solution could be using an app like "USB Camera" and sharing my phone screen in a video calling app. However, it's a bit complicated, unreliable, and, most importantly, there's a noticeable lag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.